# Segment multilanguage parallel text

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, nlp, supervised-learning, unsupervised-learning

I have multi-language text that contains a message translated to several languages.
For example:

```
English message
Russian message
Ukrainian message
```

The order is not exact.
I would like to devise some kind of supervised/unsupervised learning algorithm to do the segmentation automatically, and extract each translation in order to create a parallel corpus of data.

Could you suggest any papers/approaches? 
I am not able to get the proper keywords for googling.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your aim and/or give an example ? I'm not sure I understand what you're looking for.

Comment: Given one file with a message in 3 languages, I would to get 3 files (called en, ru, ua) that contain a message in the corresponding language. It seems to me clusterization algorithms might work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most basic approach to your problem would be to generate a [bag of words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model)  from your document. To sum up, a bag of word is a matrix where each row is a line in your document and each column a distinct term.

For instance, if your document is like this :

```
hello world
привет мир
привіт світ
```

You will have this matrix :

```
     hello | world | привет | мир | привіт | світ
l1 | 1     |    1  |   0    | 0   |   0    | 0
l2 | 0     |    0  |   1    | 1   |   0    | 0
l3 | 0     |    0  |   0    | 0   |   1    | 1
```

You can then apply classifications algorithms (such as k-means or svms) according to your needs.

For more details, I would suggest to read [this paper](http://www.jair.org/media/2934/live-2934-4846-jair.pdf) which provides a great summary of techniques.

Regarding keywords for googling, I would say `text analysis`, `text mining` or `information retrieval` are a good start.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try some language identification software? They are reporting > 90% accuracy:

- langid.py https://github.com/saffsd/langid.py
- TextCat http://odur.let.rug.nl/~vannoord/TextCat/
- Linguine http://www.jmis-web.org/articles/v16_n3_p71/index.html